# Convert .htaccess rewrite rule for showing a custom 404 to be php-fpm friendly

Tags: php, web, http-status-code-404

I'm reinstall server on Ubuntu 20.04 with control panel "Hestia" with php-fpm support.
But i have 404 error in front page domain.com/ if i use in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en/|ua/|) $1404.php [L]
```

All others pages and front page if i add /index ( domain.com/index ) works fine.
If I comment this rules - all works and front page too, but i not have my 404 page.

Please help convert my .htaccess to php-fpm friendly. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rewrite rules for non-existing files to a 404 handler is not the standard way to show a custom 404.  I would implement this using the `ErrorDocument` directive.

- In `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

  ```sh
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
  ```
- In `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/en/.htaccess`:

  ```sh
  ErrorDocument 404 /en/404.php
  ```
- In `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/ua/.htaccess`:

  ```sh
  ErrorDocument 404 /ua/404.php
  ```